# Is it acceptable to join a bug report to a job application?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, applications

I'm writing an job application email to a smallish software company as a junior back-end developer, while researching the company I stumbled upon a front-end bug,nothing website breaking.

I don't know if the manager/senior developer will take that post scriptum as a show off or as a helpful tip?

Comment: @DarkCygnus while the situation is a bit different from the other subject, as this bug isn't really visible and I don't think they know about it. But the answers are relevant my question. Thanks

Comment: I still included an answer for you to consider, besides the valuable ones given there :)

Comment: Glad I came here just before sending the email. Thanks again!

Comment: If you found the bug doing something a normal user can do, I'd report it to whatever contact is listed on the website itself like a normal user that just want to report a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know if the manager/senior dev will take that post scriptum as a show off or as a helpful tip?

I think that you should **refrain from saying so**, at least for now.

Currently, you are not hired by them (although you may be in the future), so it is not your responsibility yet to evaluate their website.

Mentioning such thing may come as a bit arrogant or they may not take that feedback too happily, and is clearly out of focus for the application process; these things can affect your application in a negative way.

If/when you get hired, then you can mention such things without problem.

Comment: The fact that the OP is not hired is not a reason to not report a bug on a company website if the OP find it doing something normal and there is a generic contact address (something like info@... webmaster@.... ). Granted, he should not report it to the manager/senior dev as a post scriptum but he should report the bug in another mail.

Comment: @Gianluca **IF** there is a generic address, which we don't know yet, then it could be viable to report it, but otherwise doing it during the application process may not be the best move.... still that is your point of view, and it's ok, although reporting it could make sense, from a hiring perspective this may not be seen as something too positive (check the dupe question's answers as well). During an interview would make more sense, but still has to be done carefully